# got a problem with the package youtube-to-mp3

Tags: 14.04, package-management, lxde

When ever I try to install or remove a package in Ubuntu 14.04, I get an error that 'youtube-to-mp3' could not be configured. I tried to remove it, but that is also not possible. Most recently I tried to get rid of the gnome environment and it returned this:

```
Setting up youtube-to-mp3 (3.5) ...
ootync.deb: supersh.deb script '/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-to-mp3.postinst' error code 127 (line 19: 'gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor > /dev/null 2>&1')
dpkg: error processing package youtube-to-mp3 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Since I could not find a similar question, I am hoping that someone can help me. This is my first question here and I am not sure if I am doing it right...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

although it did not work when I posted the original question, I tried it again and deleted 'youtube-to-mp3' with

```
sudo apt-get purge youtube-to-mp3
```

and it worked. The package is gone but the icon [actually the icon is gone and just the name] remains in the desktop menu. Installing/Removing of other apps and packages is working fine and without error again.

*I am not sure but I think when I tried to delete the package before I used
`sudo apt-get remove` instead of `purge`. So maybe that was the solution.*